Как в pyfirmata использовать сторонние библиотеки arduino
Нужно использовать библиотеку для датчика погоды, Можно ли использовать эту библиотеку через pyfirmata? Встроенную  библиотеку SERVO можно использовать просто импортировав ее из pyfirmata, а как импортировать сторонние? Большое спасибо.
